# Concatenation of strings by for xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string-concatenation, for-xml-path

Hi!
Today I learned `for xml path` technique to concatenate strings in mssql. Since I've never worked with xml in mssql and google hasn't helped, I need to ask you.

Let's imagine the default case. We need to concatenate some strings from a table:

```
declare @xmlRepNames xml = (
    select          
        ', [' + report_name + ']'
    from (
        select distinct
            report_order,
            report_name
        from #report
    ) x
    order by
        report_order
    for xml path(''), type)

select
    stuff((select @xmlRepNames.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')), 1, 1, '')
```

So I get smth like this:

```
[str1], [str2], [strn]
```

Ok. It works fine. But I have two very similar concatenate blocks. The difference is just in the way the result string looks like:

- `[str1], [str2], [strn]`

  and
- `isnull([str1], 0) as [str1], isnull([str2], 0) as [str2], isnull([strn], 0) as [strn]`

So I can write 2 very similar code blocks (already done, btw) with different string constructors or to try extend previous code to has xml variable containing 2 kind of constructors and then concatenate by xml node type. Doing 2nd way I met some problems - I wrote this:

```
declare @xmlRepNames xml = (
    select
        ', [' + report_name + ']' as name,
        ', isnull([' + report_name + '], 0) as [' + report_name + ']' as res
    from (
        select distinct
            report_order,
            report_name
        from #report
    ) x
    order by
        report_order
    for xml path(''), type)

select
    stuff((select @xmlRepNames.value('/name', 'nvarchar(max)')), 1, 1, ''),
    stuff((select @xmlRepNames.value('/res', 'nvarchar(max)')), 1, 1, '')
```

but it raise error `"XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'"`. 
To replace, e.g., `'/name'` to `'/name[1]'` or any other `'/name[x]'`, will return just x-th 'name' record but not all 'name' records concatenated. 
**[question]**: is it possible to solve problem 2nd way like I want and if it's possible then how?
**[disclaimer]**: the problem isn't really serious for me now (1st way just a little bit uglier but also fine), but it seems very interesting how to come over :)
Thanks!

Comment: [Row concatenation with FOR XML, but with multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749041/row-concatenation-with-for-xml-but-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery cannot return two values. If you just want to concatenate strings, you do not need the `xml` data type at all.  You can do the `stuff()` and subquery in a single statement:

```
declare @Rep1Names nvarchar(max) = (
    stuff((select ', [' + report_name + ']' as name
           from (select distinct report_order, report_name
                 from #report
                ) x
           order by report_order
           for xml path('')
          )
         ), 1, 1, '');

declare @Rep2Names nvarchar(max) = (
    stuff(select ', isnull([' + report_name + '], 0) as [' + report_name + ']' as res
           from (select distinct report_order, report_name
                 from #report
                ) x
           order by report_order
           for xml path('')
          )
   ), 1, 1, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I haven't been completely satisfied the way Gordon Linoff suggested and since I've found this kind of problem actual for me I'm adding here another solution without using `for xml path`:

```
declare
    @pivot_sequence nvarchar(max),
    @columns_sequence nvarchar(max)

select
    @pivot_sequence = coalesce(@pivot_sequence + ', [', '[') 
        + col_name + ']',
    @columns_sequence = coalesce(@columns_sequence + ', ', '')
        + 'isnull([' + col_name + '], 0) as [' + col_name + ']'
from some_table
order by
    /* some_columns if needed to order concatenation */
```

Obviously, it'll work much slower but in cases when you haven't many rows it won't drastically affect on performance. In my case I have dynamic pivot query and these strings are built for it - I won't have many columns in pivot so it's fine for me.