# Having Trouble Using "AND" Operator to Display Desired Results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Having difficulty in getting the query to retrieve desired results using the "**AND**" operator.  Need to show the people's `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, and `courseID` in `districtIDNum=5` who have completed any of the 3 courses, namely **(Health Old (courseIDNum=11)** *OR* **Health New (courseIDNum=12)) AND (PE Old (courseIDNum=68** *OR* **PE New (courseIDNum=177)) AND courseIDNum=128**.  Please know that `11` and `12` are actually the same course: one is an old course and the other is new (same with `68` and `177`), hence, people in districtIDNum=5 can only take one or the other; that's why I tried using (11, 12).  However, it doesn't work correctly as it returns 0 rows.

```
SELECT max(p.FirstName),
       max(p.LastName),
       max(p.Email),
       max(s.CourseIDNum)
FROM People p
INNER JOIN Registration r
   on p.PeopleID = r.PeopleIdNum
INNER JOIN Section s
   on r.SectionIDNum = s.SectionID
INNER JOIN School sc
   on p.SchoolIDNum = sc.SchoolID
WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12)
  AND s.CourseIDNum IN (68, 177)
  AND s.CourseIDNum=128
  AND sc.DistrictIDNum = 5
  AND r.Completed='Y'
group by p.PeopleID
having count(distinct s.CourseIDNum)=1
```

Row that should *NOT* be returned is `Liz M` from `districtIDNum=12` who completed `courseIDNum=195`. On the hand, `Esther B` from `districtIDNum=5` has completed `courseIDs 11, 177 and 128`; therefore, her data should display all 3 courseIDs. The data should also show that `Tommy L` has completed `courseIDs 12 and 68`.

Here are the sample tables:

peopleID   FirstName   LastName   Email                     schoolIDNum
1               Esther         B                b@hotmail.com      33
2               Tommy        L                 l@hotmail.com       55
3               Liz               M                m@hotmail.com     90

registrationID   peopleIDNum   sectionIDNum
22                    1                      40
23                    2                      41
24                    3                      132
25                    1                      78
26                    2                      52
27                    1                      63

sectionID   courseIDNum
40              11
41              12
52              68
63              128
78              177
132            195

courseID   coursename
11             Health (Old)
12             Health (New)
68             PE (Old)
128           Keyboarding
177           PE (New)
195           Computing

schoolID   districtIDNum
33             5
55             5
90             12

Answer (score 1):

The way you state the query condition

```
 s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12)
 AND s.CourseIDNum IN (68, 177)
 AND s.CourseIDNum=128
```

means that CourseIDNum must equal a set of integers *at the same time*.

```
SELECT p.FirstName,
       p.LastName,
       p.Email
FROM People p
WHERE p.PeopleID IN
(
    SELECT r.PeopleIdNum
    FROM Registration r
    INNER JOIN Section s
       on r.SectionIDNum = s.SectionID
    INNER JOIN School sc
       on p.SchoolIDNum = sc.SchoolID
    WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12, 68, 177, 128)
      AND sc.DistrictIDNum = 5
      AND r.Completed='Y'
)
```

Once you have the list of persons, retrieve their CourseIDs by concatenating Section records as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082863/concatenation-of-strings-by-for-xml-path) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488020/what-is-your-most-useful-sql-trick-to-avoid-writing-more-code/498446#498446).

Comment: I tried your script and the rows returned seem correct, however, I don't know much about concatenating so it may take me awhile to get the results I need.  I will let you know how it turns out.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't think I quite grasp the concatenating the Section records from the links you sent me.  I apologize as I'm really new to programming and it's all self-taught.  Can you kindly give me simpler examples?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12)
  AND s.CourseIDNum IN (68, 177)
  AND s.CourseIDNum=128
```

Your this portion means you are writing the query something like this

```
WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11,12,68,177) and courseIDNum = 128
```

This means CourseID num in one case can be equal to 11 , 12, 68, 177 and at the same time it should be equal to 128.... which wont be possible.
So i am not sure, but try using like

```
WHERE (s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12,68,177)
  OR s.CourseIDNum=128)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I used `WHERE (s.CourseIDNum IN (11,12,68,177,128) OR s.CourseIDNum=128)` and it returns 1 row, but there should be more rows returned.