# SQL Get columns data in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which Employee Punches are saved. For each date for each employee there are columns in the table as Punch1, Punch2 till Punch10.

[image]

I want all this Punch Columns data in a Single Column. e.g. If in a row i have dates stored in Punch1, Punch2, Punch3, Punc4....so on. I want all this data in a single Column.

How to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to concatenate the columns and store in a single column?

Comment: Why do you have all those columns? I'd probably go with one Punch column, and several rows per employee.

Comment: Would you like to concatenate them into a single column? Like `select (punch1 + punch2 + punch3 + punch4) AS Punch from table`?

Comment: @jarlh This is Clients database so i cannot change the table structure. If it was one punch per column then this question won't arise.

Comment: @jelliaes I want in in such a way that i can query on it further.

Comment: Please provide a sample output.

Comment: Create a view that UNION ALL's all those columns together. Then use the view instead of the table when needed. (Similar to @stakx' answer.)

Comment: @Anup: Do you want to concatenate the dates into a list, e.g. `xxxx-xx-xx, yyyy-yy-yy, zzzz-zz-zz, …`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UNPIVOT`can be used to normalize your table:

If you table is called `EmployeePunches`it would look like this:

```
SELECT UserID, Punch
FROM
(
  SELECT UserID, Punch1, Punch2, Punch3, Punch4
  FROM EmployeePunches
) AS ep
UNPIVOT 
(
  Punch FOR Punches IN (Punch1, Punch2, Punch3, Punch4)
) AS up
```

Using `UNION ALL`works too, but there you will have 1select statement per Punch.
With `UNPIVOT`you only need 1 Statement and just add the Punch columns you need.

Comment: Is there any way to include 1 more column of UserID which is in EmployeePunches table.

Comment: Yes, of course! Just change the inner select (alias ep) to something like `SELECT anycolumn, Punch1, Punch2, ...` and add this column in the select list above! There is a good example here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/

Answer (score 4):

### "Horizontal" (string) concatenation:

If for each row, you want to derive a new column `Punches1To10` that contains all the timestamps as e.g. a comma-separated list (such as `'xxxx-xx-xa, xxxx-xx-xb, xxxx-xx-xc, …'`), then [`FOR XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) will be what you're looking for.

See [this article](https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/) for a tutorial on this, and [the SO question "Row concatenation with FOR XML, but with multiple columns?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749041/row-concatenation-with-for-xml-but-with-multiple-columns)

### "Vertical" (table) concatenation:

Visually speaking, if you want to vertically stack the single columns `Punch1`, `Punch2`, etc. then you would concatenate the result of several select statements  using [`UNION ALL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx). For just two columns, this would look like this:

```
SELECT Punch1 AS Punch FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Punch2 AS Punch FROM YourTable
```

With three columns, it's going to be:

```
SELECT Punch1 AS Punch FROM Punches
UNION ALL
SELECT Punch2 AS Punch FROM Punches
UNION ALL
SELECT Punch3 AS Punch FROM Punches;
```

### Either way, consider normalizing your table first!

This could quickly get out of hand the more `PunchN` columns you have.

Therefore, may I recommend that you first redesign this table into something a little more [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

For example, instead of having several columns named `Punch1`, `Punch2`, etc. (where each of them contains the same type of data), just have two columns: one containing the `1`, `2`, etc. from the `PunchN` column names, the other containing the timestamps:

```
PunchN    Date
1         xxxx-xx-xa
1         xxxx-xx-xb
1         xxxx-xx-xc
2         xxxx-xx-xd     
2         xxxx-xx-xe     
…
```

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40627519/240733) shows, the database system can do something like this for you through [`UNPIVOT`](http://www.ingenioussql.com/2013/05/09/standard-t-sql-unpivot/).

Now, no matter how many `Punch` columns you have, your query e.g. for "vertical" concatenation would always the same:

```
SELECT Date FROM Punches;
```

(The "horizontal" concatenation would become simpler, too.)

Comment: Thank u for the answer. But i think nobody is understanding my requirement. I will try to edit the question with more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
select Employee,Punch_date,Identifier 
from YourTable
cross apply (values (Punch1,'Punch1'),
                    (Punch2,'Punch2'),
                    (Punch3,'Punch3'),
                     .......
                    (Punch4,'Punch4')) tc(Punch_date,Identifier)
```

The `Identifier` column help you to find the punch date is from which Punch number for each Employee